# How do I download contents from Ace text editor?

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

***I have all files zipped [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16-0HFtFA2_JKEHVWFtHrE_DWKntVMxIq/view?usp=sharing) if you want to view all of them yourself***

So... Ace text editor has been really complicated for me to set up. I thought I had everything down, but no. So far, I have incorporated download buttons just fine. It took me a while, but then I went the hidden element way and did this.

```
function downloadHTML() {
    var HTMLtextToSave = editor.getValue();
    var HTMLhiddenElement = document.createElement("a");

    HTMLhiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(HTMLtextToSave);
    HTMLhiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    HTMLhiddenElement.download = 'untitled.html';
    HTMLhiddenElement.click();
}
```

Everything worked great until I tried CSS. For some stupid reason, the getValue() decides to have a seizure everytime it sees a hashtag (#). It downloads all of the code up until it sees it, and then it stops. I really need a fix for this. I call my project GridOff for right now (beta). You can download what I have zipped right now [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16-0HFtFA2_JKEHVWFtHrE_DWKntVMxIq/view?usp=sharing). Here is my HTML code for the HTML editor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>ACE HTML Editor</title>
        <!-- Put editor language e.g.: Ace HTML Editor -->
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            #editor {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- Defines character set -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/stylesheet.css">
        <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
        <link type="image/x-icon" rel="shorcut icon" href="../Other/html5favicon.ico">
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/index.js"></script>
        <!-- JavaScript Index -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="editnav">
            <input type="button" id="downloadbtn" onclick="downloadHTML()" value="Download">
            <input type="button" id="openbtn" onclick="openCode()" value="Open">
            <input type="button" id="homebtn2" onclick="window.location.href = 'index.html';" value="Home">
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="togglebtn2" onclick="toggleVisibility2()" value="Toggle">
        <div id="editor">&lt;!DOCTYPE html>
&lt;html>
    &lt;head lang="">
        &lt;meta charset="">
        &lt;link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="">
        &lt;!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
        &lt;link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="">
        &lt;!-- Favicon -->
        &lt;title>&lt;/title>
    &lt;/head>
    &lt;body>
        &lt;p>Ace HTML Editor&lt;/p>
    &lt;/body>
&lt;/html></div>
        <!-- In this div, put filler text -->
        <!-- use &lt; for < -->
        <script src="../Other/Ace/ace-builds-master/src/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script>
            var editor = ace.edit("editor");
            editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
            editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
            // editor.setTheme("ace/theme/themeHere")
            // editor.session.setmode("ace/mode/languageHere")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, I cannot find a way for it to browse for only html files, open them in the editor, and edit them. If anyone has a solution to any of these issues that I'm having, feel free to comment. I'm looking for anything right now. Thank you StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI` to encode special characters like # or &

Or use

```
href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(value)], { type: "text/plain" }));
```

Comment: Changing encodeURI to encodeURIComponent was really fast and easy. worked like a charm.